Bad Image WebView2Loader.dll on windows11 Pro
on windows 10 my application is working fine. Where as on SOME of windows 11pro version 23H2 I am getting error "either not designed to run on windows or contains error Error status 0xc0000428".
As the webview2 run time is already installed by default with windows 11, could that be issue?
How can I confirm?
Are there any logs to check what is causing the error?
How or where can I check what is blocking the library or causing an error?
-Its digital signature looks ok.

I read windows updates notes, to see if something mentions that can block the library

Checked firewalls, anti-virus (Bad Image message with error code 0xc0000428. What does this mean?)

uninstalled few latest windows updates



hey did you resolve this?
Getting a similar issue.
